# questions about groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is part of the data of scaffold_table
[image]

I would like to create a summary table that returns the overall yield per ticker. The overall yield should be calculated as the total PnL per ticker divided by the last date's position per ticker

```
# Create a summary table of your average daily PnL, total PnL, and overall yield per ticker
summary_table = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_table.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])['Daily PnL'].mean())

position_ticker = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_table.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])['Position'].sum())

# the total PnL is the sum of PnL per Ticker after two years period
totals = summary_table.droplevel('Date').groupby('Ticker').sum().rename(columns={'Daily PnL':'total PnL'})

summary_table = summary_table.join(totals, on='Ticker')
summary_table = summary_table.join(position_ticker, on = ['Date','Ticker'], how='inner')
summary_table['Yield'] = summary_table.loc['2022-04-29']['total PnL']/summary_table.loc['2022-04-29']['Position']
summary_table
```

But the yield is showing NaN, could anyone take a look at my codes?
I used ['2022-04-29'] because it is the last date, but I think there are some codes to return the last date without explicitly inputting that.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
# Create a summary table of your average daily PnL, total PnL, and overall yield per ticker
summary_table = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_table.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])['Daily PnL'].mean())

# the total PnL is the sum of PnL per Ticker after two years period
totals = summary_table.droplevel('Date').groupby('Ticker').sum().rename(columns={'Daily PnL':'total PnL'})

summary_table = summary_table.join(totals, on='Ticker')
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
scaffold_table = pd.DataFrame({
'Position':[2000]*5, 
'Company':['Amazon', 'Amazon', 'Alphabet', 'Amazon', 'Alphabet'], 
'Date':['2020-05-26','2020-05-27','2020-05-27','2020-05-28','2020-05-28'],
'Ticker':['AMZN','AMZN','GOOG','AMZN','GOOG'],
'Open':[2458.,2404.9899,1417.25,2384.330078,1396.859985],
'Volume':[3568200,5056900,1685800,3190200,1692200],
'Daily Return':[-0.006164,-0.004736,0.000579,-0.003854,-0.000783],
'Daily PnL':[-12.327054,-9.472236,1.157283,-7.708126,-1.565741],
'Cumulative PnL/Ticker':[-12.327054,-21.799290,1.157283,-29.507417,-0.408459]})

print('\nscaffold_table:'); print(scaffold_table)

# Create a summary table of your average daily PnL, total PnL, and overall yield per ticker
summary_table = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_table.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])['Daily PnL'].mean())
print('\nsummary_table:'); print(summary_table)
# the total PnL is the sum of PnL per Ticker after two years period
totals = summary_table.droplevel('Date').groupby('Ticker').sum().rename(columns={'Daily PnL':'total PnL'})
print('\ntotals:'); print(totals)
summary_table = summary_table.join(totals, on='Ticker')
print('\nsummary_table:'); print(summary_table)
```

Input:

```
scaffold_table:
   Position   Company        Date Ticker         Open   Volume  Daily Return  Daily PnL  Cumulative PnL/Ticker
0      2000    Amazon  2020-05-26   AMZN  2458.000000  3568200     -0.006164 -12.327054             -12.327054
1      2000    Amazon  2020-05-27   AMZN  2404.989900  5056900     -0.004736  -9.472236             -21.799290
2      2000  Alphabet  2020-05-27   GOOG  1417.250000  1685800      0.000579   1.157283               1.157283
3      2000    Amazon  2020-05-28   AMZN  2384.330078  3190200     -0.003854  -7.708126             -29.507417
4      2000  Alphabet  2020-05-28   GOOG  1396.859985  1692200     -0.000783  -1.565741              -0.408459
```

Output:

```
summary_table:
                   Daily PnL
Date       Ticker
2020-05-26 AMZN   -12.327054
2020-05-27 AMZN    -9.472236
           GOOG     1.157283
2020-05-28 AMZN    -7.708126
           GOOG    -1.565741

totals:
        total PnL
Ticker
AMZN   -29.507416
GOOG    -0.408458

summary_table:
                   Daily PnL  total PnL
Date       Ticker
2020-05-26 AMZN   -12.327054 -29.507416
2020-05-27 AMZN    -9.472236 -29.507416
           GOOG     1.157283  -0.408458
2020-05-28 AMZN    -7.708126 -29.507416
           GOOG    -1.565741  -0.408458
```

Comment: could you please take a look at my newly edited version? Help is really appreciated!

Comment: I see that you have edited your question by incorporating changes from my answer, but you have not marked my answer as accepted. The usual protocol in a situation like this is to accept the answer (assuming it was helpful, as it apparently was in this case) and to ask a new question. Please feel free to link to your new question in a comment here, and I will be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: New question: I would like to create a summary table that returns the overall yield per ticker. The overall yield should be calculated as the total PnL per ticker divided by the last date's position per ticker. But the yield is showing NaN, could anyone take a look at my codes? I used ['2022-04-29'] because it is the last date, but I think there are some codes to return the last date without explicitly inputting that. You could find the code and image of the output in my original post. Thanks!!

Comment: @czzz0414 Just to clarify, when I recommended that you "ask a new question", what I meant was to post a completely new question on StackOverflow, different from this one.